# Are topologies induced by following families of seminorms same?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

Let $G$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R ^n$ and $D(G)$ denotes the set of smooth functions with compact support in $G$.

Consider following families of seminorms,

1. For $f\in D(G)$

> $||f||_N = \sup \{ | D^{\alpha}f(x)|: x\in G,|\alpha| \leq N \}$ for $N\in \mathbb N$.

2. Let $K_n$ be a nested sequence of compact sets which exhaust $G$ then for $f \in D(G)$ define

> $\nu_N (f) = \sup \{ | D^{\alpha}f(x)|: x\in K_N,|\alpha| \leq N \}$ for $N\in\mathbb N$.

where $\alpha$ is a multi-index.

Are topologies induced on $D(G)$ by above two families same?

My guess is NO but I am unable to prove it.

**EDIT**- I am interested in this question because on $C^\infty(G)$ we give topology induced by family 2. In chapter 6 of Rudin’s Functional Analysis, it says family 1 doesn’t give good topology on $D(G)$ (it’s not complete). But Rudin didn’t talk about family 2 even though it’s subspace topology on $D(G)$ as a subset of $C^\infty(G)$.

Comment: In the definition of $\nu_N$, you wrote $x\in K_N$. Did you mean $x\in K_m$? Since $N$ is already used as the size of the maximal multi index?

Comment: It’s $x\in K_N$. In fact it’s a topology which we give on $C^\infty (G)$.

Comment: Can you define the natural basis of neighborhoods of $0$ in both topology ? (the translates of those neighborhoods are a basis of the topology). Will a neighborhood in the 1st topology be open in the 2nd topology, or is it containing some open set of the 2nd topology ?

Comment: @reuns I tried that but couldn’t figure out!

Comment: Let $\|f\|_{K_n,n}= \sup_{x \in K_n, |\alpha| \le n}|D^\alpha f(x)|$ and $U_1(r,N) = \{  f \in C^\infty_c(G),  \forall n \le N,  \|f\|_{G,n}<r_n \}$. Is it open in the 1st topology ? Does it contain an open set in the 2nd topology ? (let $T(C^\infty_c(G), \|.\|_{K_n,n})$ be the set of open sets of the topological vector space $C^\infty_c(G), \|.\|_{K_n,n}$, then $T_2 = \bigcap_n T(C^\infty_c(G), \|.\|_{K_n,n})$)

Comment: I have added motivation for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the topology from 2, for functions in $C^\infty(\Omega)$, $\lim_n f_n = f$ can be thought as of $D^\alpha f_n \rightarrow D^\alpha f$ uniformly on any compact subsets, and for each $|\alpha| < \infty$.

One can construct $f_n\in \mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ and yet the limit $f\in C^\infty(\Omega)$ does not have compact support.

2 gives a weaker topology than 1 on $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$, since 1 is "converge uniformly" and 2 is "converge locally uniformly". For example, let $\phi$ have support in $[0,1]$, define 
$$\psi_m(x) =  \phi(x) + \phi(x-1) + \cdots + \phi(x-m)$$
this sequence is Cauchy in 2, but not Cauchy in 1. This also shows that $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ with the topology induced by 2 is not complete.  (Similar to Rudin's example on page 151.)

Comment: So we are not interested in topology 2 because it also is not complate. But how to justify the line “2 gives a weaker topology than 1 on $D(\Omega)$”?

Comment: Two families of semi-norms generate the same topology if and only if any semi-norm from one family can be bounded by some semi-norm of the other family. In this case $ \nu_N \leq C\|\cdot \|_N$ is clear, and I don't see a way to have the bound the other way around.

Comment: Maybe the more precise statement is given two families of semi-norms $\mathcal P$ and $\mathcal Q$, $\tau_P$ is finer, i.e. $\tau_Q \subset \tau_p$ if for each $q\in \mathcal {Q}$, there exist $n$ semi-norms $p_1, \cdots, p_n \in \mathcal {P}$ and a constant $C$ such that $$q\leq C \max \{ p_1, \cdots p_n\}.$$

Comment: Could you give reference for statement in your last comment?. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_convex_topological_vector_space#Continuous_linear_mappings You can look here, take $T$ to be the identity map from $(X,\tau_P)$ to $(X,\tau_Q)$, $T$ is continuous means exactly $\tau_Q \subset \tau_P$.

Comment: The family of semi-norms  $\|.\|_{K_n,n}$ on $C^\infty_c(G)$ gives a sequential topology : a sequence $(\psi_m) \in C^\infty_c(G)$ is Cauchy iff for every fixed $n$ then $\|\psi_m - \psi_{m'}\|_{K_n,n} \to 0$ as $m' > m \to \infty$. In my above comment I wanted to say that $\{ \psi \in C^\infty_c(G), \|\psi\|_{G,n} < 1\}$ is open in the 1st topology but not in the 2nd topology. In the 2nd topology the open sets are countable infinite union of the translates of the $U_{b,c,N} = \{ \psi \in C^\infty_c(G), \forall l \le N,\|\psi\|_{G,b_l} < c_l\}$ @MayureshL

Comment: Are you sure about the claim that $\psi _m$ is cauchy wrt family 2? Sorry for late question.

Comment: @MayureshL It should be easy to see with the metric explicitly. For $k,l\geq M$, $|\psi_k -\psi_l|$ will vanish on $[0, M]$. This means  $\nu_N (|\psi_k -\psi_j|)$ will all be zero for $N=1, 2,\cdots,  M'$.